# Access Azure MySQL database using workbench when azure cloud shell works

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, mysql-workbench

I keep getting the following error when attempting to connect to an azure MySQL database using MySQL WOrkbench

[image]

I have set the security options as follows:
[image]

Basically allow all IP addresses.

I can access it using azure cloud shell:

```
sean@Azure:~$ mysql --host XXXX.mysql.database.azure.com --user XXXX@YYY -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 65490
Server version: 5.6.39.0 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> help

For information about MySQL products and services, visit:
   http://www.mysql.com/
For developer information, including the MySQL Reference Manual, visit:
   http://dev.mysql.com/
To buy MySQL Enterprise support, training, or other products, visit:
   https://shop.mysql.com/

List of all MySQL commands:
Note that all text commands must be first on line and end with ';'
?         (\?) Synonym for `help'.
clear     (\c) Clear the current input statement.
connect   (\r) Reconnect to the server. Optional arguments are db and host.
delimiter (\d) Set statement delimiter.
edit      (\e) Edit command with $EDITOR.
ego       (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.
exit      (\q) Exit mysql. Same as quit.
go        (\g) Send command to mysql server.
help      (\h) Display this help.
nopager   (\n) Disable pager, print to stdout.
notee     (\t) Don't write into outfile.
pager     (\P) Set PAGER [to_pager]. Print the query results via PAGER.
print     (\p) Print current command.
prompt    (\R) Change your mysql prompt.
quit      (\q) Quit mysql.
rehash    (\#) Rebuild completion hash.
source    (\.) Execute an SQL script file. Takes a file name as an argument.
status    (\s) Get status information from the server.
system    (\!) Execute a system shell command.
tee       (\T) Set outfile [to_outfile]. Append everything into given outfile.
use       (\u) Use another database. Takes database name as argument.
charset   (\C) Switch to another charset. Might be needed for processing binlog with multi-byte charsets.
warnings  (\W) Show warnings after every statement.
nowarning (\w) Don't show warnings after every statement.
resetconnection(\x) Clean session context.

For server side help, type 'help contents'

mysql>
```

But I can't connect from my PC using workbench.  I can use workbench to connect to another database using 3306 so the port is not blocked.

I'm convinced I have done something wrong on azure but don't know what it is.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you try to disable SSL, are you able to connect? Otherwise, do you have another server that you can connect to? Trying to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a bitnami MySQL instance but ran into problems too (Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded).  I came across a tip to upgrade Workbench.

The tip didn't work but it did fix my original issue with the azure database.

The solution: upgrade workbench.

Honestly, I think this is ridiculously stupid.  Why don't they have a validation tool that can be run after launching an instance?  It would probably take a day to engineer...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft documentation about how to connect with workbench:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-workbench

How to configure SSL: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl
 I think your forgot to do this part.

Comment: just tried to configure the SSL using the cert listed and got exactly the same response (pulls out hair ).  Thanks for suggestions.